# How to submit data on pressing enter key (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax php comment system which works fine but it submits data on pressing comment button. I want to give some fancy touch and remove comment button, means comment will be submitted on enter key.

```
<form method='post' name='form' action=''>
<input type='text' name='comment' id='comment' placeholder='Write a comment....' />
<input type='button' name='submit' id='submit' value='Comment'/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
     $("#submit").click(function() {
        var test = $("#comment").val();
        var comment = test;
        var id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
        if (test == '') {
          alert("Please Enter Some Text");
        } else {

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment.php",
            data: {comment : comment,id : id},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
              $(".coments").prepend(html);
              $("#comment").val('');
            }
          });

        }
        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Code above is with comment button and works fine. Now I am trying to submit comment on enter key:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
     $('#comment').keyup(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var test = $("#comment").val();
        var comment = test;
        var id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
        if (test == '') {
          alert("Please Enter Some Text");
        } else {

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment.php",
            data: {comment : comment,id : id},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
              $(".coments").prepend(html);
              $("#comment").val('');
            }
          });

        }
        return false;
       }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

This code does not work on pressing enter key page is refreshed no comment is submitted.

Comment: change button type to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust `input="button"` to `<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Comment'/>`.

But if you don't want the submit button to appear you can still hide it with css`<input type='button' name='submit' id='submit' value='Comment' style="display:none;" />`

And then you do your magic to submit the form using jQuery

```
        $(function() {
      $('#comment').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

           var test = $("#comment").val();
  var comment = test;
  var id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
  if (test == '') {
    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
  } else {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "comment.php",
      data: {comment : comment,id : id},
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $(".coments").prepend(html);
        $("#comment").val('');
      }
    });

    }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to reload the page, I suggest you change the form element to a div element. This way, you handle the requests yourself.

```
<div>
  <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment' placeholder='Write a comment....' />
  <input type='button' name='submit' id='submit' value='Comment' />
</div>
```

Here's a quick fiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/w2fepLak/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button type submit, then it'll automatically submit when pressing the enter key - no JS, no magic needed!

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Comment'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Submitting on enter is actually default behavior here. What you want to do is hook in to the `submit` event, rather than trying to catch everything that will later cause a `submit` event. So:

- Listen for just `submit` on the form element, not `click` or `keydown`.
- In the `submit` handler, call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting and reloading the page.

In code:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var test = $("#comment").val();
  var comment = test;
  var id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
  if (test == '') {
    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
  } else {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "comment.php",
      data: {comment : comment,id : id},
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $(".coments").prepend(html);
        $("#comment").val('');
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will automatically submit when there is only one `input[type=text]` in the form and press a enter in the input.

To fix this, you can simply add another useless `input[type=text]` under the form like this:

```
<form method='post' name='form' action=''>
    <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment' placeholder='Write a comment....' />
    <input type="text" style="display: none;" name="nothing" value="nothing" />
    <input type='button' name='submit' id='submit' value='Comment'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay without `<form>` tag. Remove it and you are good to go.